# How can I increase the number of polygons / resolution for this plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have generated the following plot:

[image]

Code:

```
RegionPlot3D[  x^2 + z^2 < 1 &&   x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Axes -> False]
```

However, the resolution is a bit poor in the plot above. How can I increase the polygon count or increase the resolution some other way?

Comment: Try changing `Mesh`  and `PlotPoints` See help http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegionPlot3D.html for options

Comment: Plot points did the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Grid[{RegionPlot3D[
     x^2 + z^2 < 1 && x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Axes -> False, 
     Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> #, ViewPoint -> {2, 0, 2}, Boxed -> False] & /@ 
                                                                         {Automatic, 10, 20, 100}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Just change `PlotPoints`. Here values between 10 and 100:

[image]

Creation code:

```
gr = Table[
   Rasterize@
    RegionPlot3D[
     x^2 + z^2 < 1 && x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 
      2}, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> i, Mesh -> All], {i, 10, 100, 
    5}];

Export["tmp/resolution.gif", Join[gr, Reverse[gr]], 
 "DisplayDurations" -> .3]
```